# FileResolver, environment variable and ivyde

Tags: ivyde

I have an ant/ivy project that I'm also using in Eclipse.  The problem is that in eclipse, ivyde is complaining about the FileResolver in my ivysettings.xml, claiming that the path must be absolute.  The reason, I believe, is that it's failing to evaluate an environment variable.

The following is my ivysettings.xml file, which ivyde fails to parse due to this absolute path requirement:

```
<ivysettings>
  <properties environment="env"/>
  <properties file="./ivysettings.properties"/>
  <settings defaultResolver="chain"/>
  <resolvers>
    <filesystem name="local">
      <ivy pattern="${repository.dir}/[module]/ivy.xml" />
      <artifact pattern="${repository.dir}/[module]/[artifact].[ext]" />
    </filesystem>
    <chain name="chain">
       <resolver ref="local"/>
       <ibiblio name="maven2" m2compatible="true"/>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
  <modules>
    <module organisation="org.example" resolver="local"/>
  </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

ivysettings.properties contains:

```
repository.dir=${env.githome}/metademo/ivy_build/repository
```

Ant is happy with this, but ivyde doesn't seem to resolve {$env.githome}.  I need some way to do this 'absolute path' requirement for the FileSystem resolver for different developer environments... so using a environment variable to reference it.  How do I get ivyde to recognize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make a config work in different environment like Ant or Eclipse, it should be independent of any external variables. The ivysettings.xml file and property files should be sufficient to resolve any path.

Here you have set `env.*` properties via Ant. You should better let Ivy do it itself with the `properties` and its `environment`attribute.

cf http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/properties.html

Comment: Thanks for answering Nicolas.  I'm confused though, by your statement that I'm using ant to set the env.* properties.  The properties are being loaded in ivysettings.xml, which the ant ivy:settings target will load, or the ivyde will load.

Comment: I don't have the full context, but I guess that somewhere in your build you have `<property environment="env"/>`. So when Ivy is running within Ant, as it can see the Ant properties, it can properly resolve `env.githome`. Hence my suggestion to do that `env.*` property setting within Ivy rather than within Ant.

Comment: My other problem was getting eclipse (as an application) to see the environment variables.. mac developers: launchctl setenv <varname> <varvalue>